# HighCharts Keep Vertical Line on Click Event

Tags: highcharts

Using this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/

When you hover over points on the chart, you get a nice vertical line showing you which point you're currently on.  I want to modify the click event so that the vertical line stays when I hover away after a click.  Changing the line color would be ideal on click, but not necessary.

If I click another point I'd want to remove any previous lines.  Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in several ways

Highchart has a very cool [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Renderer) that allows you to add various graphics to the chart. One of the options is to add a [path](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp) I will be illustrating the same here.

We shall reuse the path of the crosshair and add the same to the chart with some additional styles like color you mentioned. The path of the crosshair can be optained as `this.tooltip.crosshairs[0].d` this is in string form and can be easily converted to an array using the `Array.split()` function

```
click: function() {
    this.renderer.path(this.tooltip.crosshairs[0].d.split(" ")).attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
         stroke: 'red'
  }).add();
}
```

This will accomplish adding the line. You can store the returned object into a global variable and then when you are about to add another such line, you can destroy the existing one by calling [`Element.destroy()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Element.destroy%28%29)

```
 var line;
 ...
 chart:{
    events: {
        click: function() {

            if (line) {
                line.destroy();
            }
            line = this.renderer.path(this.tooltip.crosshairs[0].d.split(" ")).attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'red'
            }).add();

        }
    }
...
```

[Persist tooltip / crosshair on click @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/Jee8R/)

Assuming you don't have much meta data to be shown along with the line, this is the easiest (or the coolest :) ) approach. You can also attach meta data if you want to using the renderer's text object etc.

An alternate way could be [adding vertical plotLines to the xAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.addPlotLine%28%29)

## UPDATE

Refer my other solution to this question, that would work with zoom,scroll,etc

Answer (score 4):

[The above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061734/1566575) like I said, is really cool, but is kind of a hack (getting the path of the crosshair) into the implementation details of highcharts, and may stop working in future releases, may not be totally cross browser (esp since <IE8 do not support SVG, the adding path may still work as it should be handled by highchart's add path method, but getting the crosshair's path may not work, I may be wrong, am an SVG noob). So here I give you the alternate solution of [dynamically adding plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.addPlotLine%28%29). PlotLines also allow some additional features like dashStyles, label etc.

get the axis and x value of point clicked (may not exactly overlap the crosshair)

```
            var xValue = evt.xAxis[0].value;
            var xAxis = evt.xAxis[0].axis;
```

Or

**EDIT** If you want to have the plotLine at the location of the crosshair and not the click position, you can use following formula (*No direct API to get this, obtained from source code hence may stop working if code changes*)

```
            var chart = this;
            var index = chart.inverted ? chart.plotHeight + chart.plotTop - evt.chartY : evt.chartX - chart.plotLeft;
            var xValue = chart.series[0].tooltipPoints[index].x;
```

Add plotline

```
           xAxis.addPlotLine({
                value: xValue,
                width: 1,
                color: 'red',
                //dashStyle: 'dash',                   
                id: myPlotLineId
            });
```

You can cleanup existing plotline

```
            $.each(xAxis.plotLinesAndBands,function(){
                if(this.id===myPlotLineId)
                {
                    this.destroy();
                }
            });
```

OR

```
            try {
                xAxis.removePlotLine(myPlotLineId);
            } catch (err) {}
```

Putting the pieces together

```
   var myPlotLineId="myPlotLine";
   ...
           var chart=this;
           index = chart.inverted ? chart.plotHeight + chart.plotTop - evt.chartY : evt.chartX - chart.plotLeft;
           var xValue =  chart.series[0].tooltipPoints[index];

           // var xValue = evt.xAxis[0].value; // To use mouse position and not crosshair's position
           var xAxis = evt.xAxis[0].axis;

            $.each(xAxis.plotLinesAndBands,function(){
                if(this.id===myPlotLineId)
                {
                    this.destroy();
                }
            });
            xAxis.addPlotLine({
                value: xValue,
                width: 1,
                color: 'red',
                //dashStyle: 'dash',                   
                id: myPlotLineId
            });
   ...
```

[Add plot lines at click position @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/wHnnE/) 
[Persist crosshair/cursor as plot lines on click @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/G7v8a/)

Comment: I find that plotLines are a better approach and they can be turned on/off easily.

Comment: @Jugal - This does seem like a much better approach, but I noticed in a few samples the plot line is a few pixels off from the hover.  Can anything be done about that?

Comment: Like i said in the post, it may not exactly overlap the cursor/mouse position. Reasons being the spacing between points is larger than resolution of mouse, so there may not be a corresponding X value to the place you clicked, in which case the crosshair will be placed at the nearest point. When you use the click event arg, you get the plotline exactly where you clicked without rounding to the nearest point(where the crosshair appears to be) hence the crosshair and the new line may not overlap. If you want to add a line to where the crosshair is not the mouse position, check updated answer

Comment: @Jugal - Thanks, I was able to get it to work on a Candlestick chart by looking up the actual value of the candlestick center.  This works great as a chart click event, but if I wanted to move it to a series click event, what would I change evt.xAxis[0].axis; to find the xAxis?