# set value from xAxis.plotline live Highstock

Tags: charts, highcharts

I use Highstock and I would set the value from a xAxis.plotLine by a point click event. How can I do this so that it is displayed directly?
I set the value on click event with xAxis.plotLines.value = this.x;

```
  series : [
      {
    xField : 'deltaTime',
    yField : 'variableOne'
  },{
    xField : 'deltaTime',
    yField : 'variableTwo',
  }],
  chartConfig : {          
        xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            width: 2,
            color: 'black'
        }]
    },
    rangeSelector : {
      selected : 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {                           
                        var hcConfig = Chart.ux.HistoryChart.getConfig('single_line');
                        hcConfig.chartConfig.xAxis.plotLines.value = this.x;
                        }
                        }
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a plot line after the chart is created, you have to call the [`addPlotLine`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Axis) method of the xAxis object of your chart.  You can access that from the `event` parameter passed into your click handler:

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function(event) {
            event.point.series.xAxis.addPlotLine({ ... });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dascoco Glad I could help and welcome to SO.  If this answered your question click the green arrow to the left to confirm the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered a similar question @ [HighCharts Keep Vertical Line on Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061230/highcharts-keep-vertical-line-on-click-event).
[Add plot lines at click position @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/wHnnE/)